# Moving away from MD5: Where to declare the custom global $wp_hasher?

Tags: security, password, encryption

I want to move away from using MD5 for hashing passwords in the database. The plan is to declare a custom global `$wp_hasher` as hinted at in the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password) for `wp hash password()`:

> Unless the global $wp_hasher is set, the default implementation uses PasswordHash, which adds salt to the password and hashes it with 8 passes of MD5.

I want to declare `$wp_hasher` like this (Blowfish or extended DES, 16 rounds of hashing):

```
global $wp_hasher;
$wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(16, FALSE);
```

Where do I put this code so that the custom `$wp_hasher` is declared by the time it's referenced in `wp_hash_password()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is this: Since `wp_hash_password()` is a "pluggable" function, create a simple plugin or MU-Plugin and define a function called `wp_hash_password()` in that plugin/mu-plugin. Wordpress will use your function instead of the core function.

Just copy the original code into your plugin/mu-plugin and change the one relevant line.

Answer (score 1):

Too late to answer but for someone still looking for a solution ->

Create a plugin and write below code:

```
    function wp_hash_password( $password ) {
      global $wp_hasher;
      require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php' );
      $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash( 16, false );  
      return $wp_hasher->HashPassword( trim( $password ) );
    }
```